# Passing multiple arguments in NSInvocation for a method with variable arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I have a method which take variable arguments something like this, the arguments end with nil.

```
-(void)manyParams:(NSString *)st, ... {
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList,st);

    id obj;

    while ((obj = va_arg(argList, id))) {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    }
    va_end(argList);

    return;
}
```

I can call it directly like this

```
[self manyParams:@"one",@"two",@"three",nil];
```

If I am using `NSInvocation` class to invoke the manyParams then how can I do this

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(manyParams:)];
///NSString *one = @"one";
///[invocation setArgument:&one atIndex:2]; //////How to pass variable arguments like @"one",@"two",@"three", nil
[invocation invoke];
```

Answer (score 5):

NSInvocation does not support variadic methods, so this will not be possible. (Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html )

> NSInvocation does not support invocations of methods with either
>   variable numbers of arguments or union arguments.

If there is an alternate version of the method that takes a `va_list` and all your parameters are object pointers you might be able to fake something up like in my answer over here: [fake va_list in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211996/fake-va-list-in-arc/8217755#8217755)

Comment: C unions. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm