# Double value validation in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to check if NSString is numeric or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020360/how-to-check-if-nsstring-is-numeric-or-not)
>   [iphone how to check that a string is numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only)

I would like to validate a `UITextField` input.

I want that the input must be a `double`, and I want to detect if there are any strange characters as `"()?` etc.

Is there an easy way to detect that the input is a correct `double` better than the following?

```
if ([amount doubleValue] <= 0.0f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must validate "**amount**" string value before casting it to double, for example you can check if it contains "**.**" or something else ... Or you do conversation in try catch and if your string will contain "(" or "()" or ... it will catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the approach, which you used is very quick and simple, would suggest you to go with this only

```
- (double)doubleValue
```

**Return Value description from apple doc.**

> The floating-point value of the
>   receiver’s text as a double. Returns
>   HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0
>   on underflow. Returns 0.0 if the
>   receiver doesn’t begin with a valid
>   text representation of a
>   floating-point number.