# iOS - how do I check if a string is numeric or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone how to check that a string is numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only)

I am trying to look up some basic functionality in Objective C, but can't seem to locate the basic answer.

What I really need is to check

```
if ( some_string is numeric )
{

}
```

I would assume there would just be some built in function for that.  No?

I am looking at this StackOverflow question [How to check if NSString is numeric or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020360/how-to-check-if-nsstring-is-numeric-or-not) and they seem to be doing things the very complicated way.

Isn't there some basic check I can do in one simple line?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "numeric"! Are only digits allowed? Minus? Decimal dot? Scientific notation? Different locales? What else...

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe yeah whole number like 4536

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Isn't there some basic check I can do in one simple line?

No.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
BOOL isNumeric = [scanner scanInteger:NULL] && [scanner isAtEnd];
```

If you want to allow decimal digits exchange `scanInteger:` by `scanDouble:`.

Comment: Is there any performance penalty on this like with a NSDateFormatter?

Comment: @agarcian No, NSScanner is quite lightweight.

Comment: Does this allow negative numbers too? i.e.: -23.2351