# Handling credit cards and IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSUrlConnection asyncronous request to transmit credit card information to a secure third party server.

I do the following:

1. I get the credit card number, cvv, etc from the uitextfields.
2. Encode the credit card information into a json format. Set as httpd body of the `NSURLConnection` request as follows:

   ```
   NSDictionary * params = @{"creditCardNumber": @"4242....", @"cvv": @"455"....
   NSURL * url = [[NSURL URLWithString: "https://www.example.com"];

   NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];

   [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   [request setHTTPBody: [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: params options: kNilOptions error: &parseError]];
   ```
3. Send this information via asynchronous request to a secure third party server:

   ```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                                  queue: queue
                                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData  *data, NSError * requestError) {
   ```

What should I be considering to send user credit card information to a third party server using nsurlconnection asynchronous request?

Is this the right way to send credit card information from a mobile app?

What can I do to prevent man in the middle attack?

Comment: user data security :)

Comment: please rewrite the question as it has nothing to do with credit card handling. it is irrelevant if it is credit card data or ... something else AFAICS

Comment: Details are probably described in the API of the payment provider that you are using. Make sure that you send delicate data only trough secure connection (HTTPS) and only to the specified provider hook. From there on "forget" about CC number and CCV and deal only with tokens (encrypted CC object id-s) that your server provider provides you. If your app requiers to communicate with your own server also it might be a good time to consider implementing there, too (some payment providers even demand that - but usually for web applications).

Comment: How can I prevent the man in the middle attack?

Comment: Hi Daij, check out this article: http://www.indelible.org/ink/trusted-ssl-certificates/. I should be implementing the code there, right?

Comment: Fixed some typing errors in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing you may need to comply with a standard like PCI, PADSS, etc.

Besides communicating over HTTPS, the general flow of hardening against man-in-the-middle attacks involves:

- Do not store any details on the device. Storing in RAM is ok.
- The back-end instruct you to use one of many pre-fetched public encryption keys. Each key is associated with an id. You will fetch the key that it instructs you to use from your local store. You will create a hash of your deta using that key. And then send to the back-end.

For encryption, I recommend checking out the [CoocaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity) project. It wraps some of the lower level APIs making them easier to "digest" (excuse the pun).

Comment: Great answer @Jasper, I'd like to add [OWASP iOS Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks good, just make sure you are accessing via https and not http. This means your server must support https

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some king of secure authentication scheme in place for your web service, you've at least cleared the basics. Your biggest weakness is HTTPS. Especially in the mobile world, HTTPS is easily penetrated. I know that sounds a bit paranoid, but you have to think that way to stay ahead.

The next step would be apply an additional level of encryption to the payload of the request. Blowfish would be a simple and easy way to encrypt the payload.

Comment: Today (as opposed to several years ago) Blowfish should not be used for new work. Todays standard is AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). Additionally most CPUs now have instructions that meme AES faster.

Comment: Blowfish is deliberately slow. It's a feature. The other feature that makes me recommend Blowfish-based implementations is that they are secure by default. Conversely, AES is *VERY* weak by if used with a poor Key Diffusion Algorithm.

Comment: Of course slow is good, how much slower? Do you have a reference for: "AES is VERY weak by if used with a poor Key Diffusion Algorithm?" But I see see that Blowfish is the choice for "Prison Locker a.k.a Power Locker ramsomware toolkit."

Comment: Ask and you shall receive: [Common Errors using AES](http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto)

Comment: In an industry that emphasizes everything being faster, more efficient, and able to be threaded, it may seem odd that Blowfish implementations are deliberately slow, but it makes sense in the big picture. With as fast as computers are, doing an expensive operation once isn't that bad. However, brute force becomes impractical. It's similar to why Bitcoin is weak and Litecoin, by using Scrypt, is better, but more expensive computationally.

Comment: If Blowfish is 10 to 100 times slower maybe, if it is 2 times slower the speed is irrelevant. But are you really proposing a bruit force attack on 128 or 256 bit AES? As for coin, I see no security difference, that is not the reason script was chosen over hashing.

Comment: You are not suggesting using simple passwords as keys, right? You are using PBKDF2 to generate keys from passwords, right?

Comment: There is nothing in Rob's blog post that suggests any weakness in AES and the main point "Properly Encrypting With AES" applies equally to any cypher.   I hope you are not suggesting using simple passwords as keys, you are using PBKDF2 to generate keys from passwords, right?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not actually suggesting a weakness in AES. The weakness is in the key choice. Several common AES wrappers have been proven to be weak because of their KDA. I site [this one](https://gist.github.com/gonecoding/838614) for example. If a known weak KDA is used, it is extremely practical to brute force AES, whether 128-bit or 256-bit.

Comment: I don't have an explicit source for this, but Blowfish implementations are around 1000x slower than AES for startup times. Actual encryption is roughly the same, but since it takes around 1000x as long to start up, brute force attacks become impractical.

Comment: 100x or 1000x, which? Any reference to those numbers otherwise they are just FUD. So you say Blowfish is better only is a bad key is chosen? Only if a poor wrapper is chosen?  One needs to use a good key and choose a AES wrapper, that is rather obvious.  Also please define "extremely practical to brute force AES" for say a 128 or 256 bit key in number if attempts on average and how the crib is determined.

Comment: I tested AES128, AES256 and Blowfish448 with CommonCrypto with one block of data and a different key each iteration and iterated 10,000 times. Complete setup each time. This should be a worse case setup. Blowfish is 17x slower, not 100x or 1000x. Not a meaningful amount given even just a 128 bit key size for a brute force attack. There is no merit in Blowfish over AES from a security perspective. Further AES has been better mush more than Blowfish. Blowfish was great in it's day.

Comment: Lastly, iOS has FIPS-140-2 certification for AES (and others) but not Blowfish.