# How to check text is number or not in ipad?

Tags: iphone

I have implement one client server base application for ipad (sdk 3.2). I have one field price in which user enter price value.But user can enter some alphabetical text by mistake so i want to check this text is numeric or not then how it possible please give me some idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone how to check that a string is numeric only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only)

Comment: I parsed this as "How to check whether text is a number; or if it's not in the iPad"

Comment: @Smashery: Then your AI isn't very good. Context is very important for a good parser.

Comment: [refer this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL) isNumeric:(NSString *)aoInputString {

    NSCharacterSet *decimalSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];


    NSString *decTrimmed = [aoInputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:decimalSet];

    if (decTrimmed.length > 0) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    } 
}
```

Comment: @JohnWhite except that it's wrong.  This will only recognize integer values.  If you're dealing with prices, then you have to account for decimal digits (which this fails to do).

Comment: Yeah, I apparently copied a wrong part of my code. Please note this might not account for some other invalid cases, such as 12...9 (Extra decimal points), ... (non-decimal) etc. Thank Apple for making this harder than it really should be. (Regexlite might be a better option if you want a more robust solution).

Comment: except that Apple has made a way to handle this that is stupidly easy.  It's called `NSNumberFormatter`, and it will handle more than any regex you wrote would be able to.

Comment: i used this @"0123456789.+- " to check phone number with name

Answer (score 1):

Always always always the proper way to convert a string into a number is to use an `NSNumberFormatter`.  Using methods like `-floatValue` and `-intValue` can lead to false positives.

Behold:

```
NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString * good = @"42.69";
NSString * bad = @"42.69abc";
NSString * abc = @"abc";
NSString * zero = @"0";

NSLog(@"-[good floatValue]: %f", [good floatValue]);
NSLog(@"-[bad floatValue]: %f", [bad floatValue]);
NSLog(@"-[abc floatValue]: %f", [abc floatValue]);
NSLog(@"-[zero floatValue]: %f", [zero floatValue]);

NSNumber * goodNumber = [nf numberFromString:good];
NSNumber * badNumber = [nf numberFromString:bad];
NSNumber * abcNumber = [nf numberFromString:abc];
NSNumber * zeroNumber = [nf numberFromString:zero];

NSLog(@"good (NSNumber): %@", goodNumber);
NSLog(@"bad (NSNumber): %@", badNumber);
NSLog(@"abc (NSNumber): %@", abcNumber);
NSLog(@"zero (NSNumber): %@", zeroNumber);

[nf release];
```

This logs:

```
2011-01-07 09:50:07.881 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] -[good floatValue]: 42.689999
2011-01-07 09:50:07.884 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] -[bad floatValue]: 42.689999
2011-01-07 09:50:07.885 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] -[abc floatValue]: 0.000000
2011-01-07 09:50:07.885 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] -[zero floatValue]: 0.000000
2011-01-07 09:50:07.886 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] good (NSNumber): 42.69
2011-01-07 09:50:07.887 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] bad (NSNumber): (null)
2011-01-07 09:50:07.887 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] abc (NSNumber): (null)
2011-01-07 09:50:07.888 EmptyFoundation[4895:a0f] zero (NSNumber): 0
```

Observations:

- The `-floatValue` of a non-numeric string (`@"42.69abc"` and `@"abc"`) results in a false positive (of `0.000000`)
- If a string is not numeric, `NSNumberFormatter` will report it as `nil`

As an added bonus, `NSNumberFormatter` takes locale into account, so it'll (correctly) recognize "42,69" as numeric, if the current locale has `,` set as the decimal separator.

TL;DR:

## Use `NSNumberFormatter`.