# IPad - how to only type 0~9 on textfield?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitextfield

Hello
I know ipad keyboard doesn't like iphone can set "UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad"!!
But if I wanna it only can type and show number 0 to 9 on textfield.
How to compare what user key in on textfield are numbers or not ??

Thank in advance.

Mini

Comment: Answered a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12944946/868193).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only Numbers for UITextField input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only) thread. It solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 9):

instead of comparing a figure after it is displayed,  do it in the shouldChangeCharactersInRange

be sure to declare the delegate UITextFieldDelegate,  and something i always forget,  make sure the delegate of the textField itself is pointing at the class that has the code in it.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0)
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        return NO;
    }

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    if ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0)return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. It still displays the other characters, but only allows the user to select numbers

Answer (score 1):

How about [How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)?

The idea is you check every time the user hits a key, and if it is a number let it through. Otherwise ignore it.

Make your Controller supports the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and implement the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {

    NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    NSString * newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
    NSNumber * number = [nf numberFromString:newString];

    if (number) {
         return YES;

    } else
        return NO;
}
```