# UITextField - Allow only numbers and punctuation input/keypad

Tags: ios, numbers, iphone-keypad

I have tried the code below but that only allows for numbers on the keypad to be inputted. My app requires the keypad to use a period/full stop (for money transactions). The code I tried is:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

     if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet].location != NSNotFound)
      {
         return NO;
    }
   return YES;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: set your text field to: [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];

Comment: @Mutawe this does not prevent the user from changing to the `ABC` keyboard.

Comment: Answered a [similar question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12944946/868193)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this

Make a macro

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @"0123456789."
```

And use it

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    if (textField==textFieldAmount)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, whats `textFieldAmount`?

Comment: I have mulitiple textfield thats y i am checking.

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 3:**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = "0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+~:{}|\"?><\\`,./;'[]=-"
    return allowedCharacters.contains(string) || range.length == 1
}
```

Comment: @SPatel Also the question is "allow only punctuation and numbers".  `.` is punctuation

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
```

after creating your textfield.

Comment: this does not prevent the user from changing to the `ABC` keyboard.

Comment: @Gman Well I guess there is no standard keyboard that fully meets your requirements... I guess you'd have to make your own input view for that purpose though that seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: It also doesn't defend from pasting incorrect data into a textField

Answer (score 2):

How about a custom character set? Something like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *testChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789+*#-() "];
```

Because setting the keyboard type is pretty useless on iPad...