# XCODE ipad storyboard giving from keyboard layout

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

With my ipad app i want the user to have enter some values, by selecting numbers on the keyboard.
I only want to present them with the numpad, since letters don't make any sense (it's a simple calculation app).

I choose the numpad as keyboard, see:

[image: Screenshot]

But for some reason i still get the default QWERTY keyboard presented. Any help is verrrrry much appreciated, i am a total noob in ios development ;-)

Comment: Because you are not using number pad, you are using phone pad which iPad doesn't have.

Comment: The iPad does not have numeric or phone keyboard, you will have to create one yourself.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't have number pad either. It just presents the qwerty with numbers enabled.

Answer (score 0):

iPad does not have a nuberpad like iPhone but you can restrict users from typing anything other than numbers in the keypad [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input/12944946#12944946) or if you want to have only numbers you can create your own customise keyboard [this](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-make-custom-ios-number-keyboard.html) may give you an idea on how to create one .Hopefully this solves your issue.