# How to obtain numbers from a UI Textfield?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am creating a application where users will enter speeds of a car in two `textFields`, Press the `button` and the app will tell you which car is faster. I'm aware that in order to do so, you need to use `NSNumberFormatter` but do I put the code in a separate method that compares the number and call on it when the button is clicked?

Comment: Do you have `UITextField` restricted to have only integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should restrict the `UITextField`s for Decimal only values. Refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input) for the same.

Then you can do something like following:

```
-(IBAction)fasterCar:(id)sender {

    int result = [self.txtField1.text intValue]; - [self.txtField1.text intValue];

    if (result > 0)              
         NSLog(@"1st one is faster");
    else if (result < 0)         
         NSLog(@"2nd one is faster);
    else                         
         NSLog(@"Both cars have equal speed");
}
```

Might seem old school, works well.

Comment: i like the old school method but I am still getting an error. I have the labels declared as                                                        - (IBAction)carSpeed1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)carSpeed2:(id)sender;                                            do i need to write arguments for these too?

Comment: Those two you specified are not labels at all... They are IBActions.

Comment: but don't you need to connect the labels to the IBAction so the text changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSDecimal *scannerValue = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[textFieldInstance stringValue]] scanDecimal:scannerValue];
if ([scannerValue decimalValue] != [NSDecimalNumber zero]) { // got a number
} else { // not a number
}
```

The methods available are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDecimalNumber) with links to the class hierarchy. If you should need further help, do leave a comment.

Comment: Hmm, what would be the benefit of using this instead of, say, using `NSCharacterSet` to validate that the text is a number and then using `floatValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your button action method below:-

```
-(IBAction)calculateSpeed:(id)sender
{
    NSDecimalNumber *first=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.txt.text];
    NSDecimalNumber *second=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.txt2.text];
    (second > first) ? NSLog(@"Mclaren is faster") : NSLog(@"BMW is faster");
}
```