# Sum of three textfield value without clicking a button (Swift - Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently having problems for my label to read the addition of 3 textfield values automatically, without a button function action. As such i only want my textfield to be an Int input only. There's a screenshot attached below for better reference. Appreciate those who can help me with this. Thanks!

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class TryingoutController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var impact: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var rigour: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var response: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var total: UILabel!
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to add `self` as the target to the text fields, for the control event `.editingChanged`

```
impact.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged), for: .editingChanged)
// do the same for other textfields
```

Then declare a `textChanged` method. This should handle what happens when the texts in the text fields change. One implementation would be to add up all the values in the text fields (if any, and is valid) and display it in the label.

```
func textChanged() {
    let impactValue = Int(impact.text!)
    let rigourValue = Int(rigour.text!)
    let responseValue = Int(response.text!)
    total.text = String(describing: 
        (impactValue ?? 0) + (rigourValue ?? 0) + (responseValue ?? 0)
    )
}
```

Optionally, you can conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
class TryingoutController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

and implement `shouldChange` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input/12944946#12944946) by Thuggish Nuggets. Then, set the `delegate`s of the text fields to `self`:

```
impact.delegate = self
// do the same for other text fields.
```

Comment: `response.text ?? "0"` does that help ? Also may be its helpful if `shouldChange` delegate is implemented to restrict character set to numbers.

Comment: you can do that with this answer -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input/12944946#12944946

Comment: @Skywalker Thanks, added a link to that answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but 1 last thing, how can i validate my "impact" textfield? so that the user can only input from 1 - 80?

Comment: @Kinja You will have to use if statements to check whether the input is in range. And output an appropriate message using the label if any of them is out of range.

Comment: and what would be the appropriate code for the if statement to check? i tried  if (impact.text != 1..80) { } but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kinja You should check `impactValue` instead. e.g. `impactValue >= 1 && impactValue <= 80`.

Comment: @Sweeper btw mate, there's an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'impactValue'" when using impactValue

Comment: @Kinja I think you should do some research first, then ask another question.