# How to check if contents of a string are numeric values?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only) but it is 2 years old. Is there a better\easier\newer way to check if string has numeric values. e.g 1 or 1.54 or -1 or -1.54 etc etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an NSString into an NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber)

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I added that method and attribution to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bool status;
NSScanner *scanner;
NSString *testString;
double result;

scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
status = [scanner scanDouble:&result];
status = status && scanner.scanLocation == string.length;
```

If status == YES then the string is fully numeric.

Or as @Dave points out from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448804/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-into-an-nsnumber/1448875#1448875):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
number = [formatter numberFromString:string];
status = number != nil;
```

(I'm not leaking, I'm using ARC :-))

Comment: For a the few weeks that I have spent in Objective C I will take any thing to avoid alloc\init.BTW `(I'm not leaking, I'm using ARC :-))`please elaborate might be handy tip for a beginner like myself.

Comment: Well, if `alloc/init` bother you so much you can use `new` albeit it is deprecated: NSNumberFormatter *formatter = `[NSNumberFormatter new];` but I don't suggest that.  ARC (Automatic Referencing Counting), available in Xcode 4.2 and IOS 4.3 and above eliminates the need for `retain`, `release' or `autorelease`, in fact they are not allowed.  OK, my comment: it is common to get a comment that a release is missing from a code snippet, my snarky comment was directed to that possibility, eventually we will need to come to grips with release/autorelease not being necessary in code under ARC.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `[NSString floatValue]`

Comment: Thant won't work, it will return 0 for garbage, the same as for @"0".

Comment: the question is not how to convert but how to check if the string can be converted to some numeric value