# Insert into table only if numeric in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an insert query like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_LandRigs (Company,Rig,[RigType] ,[DrawWorks],[TopDrive] ) VALUES 
(@Company,@Rig,@RigType ,@DrawWorks,@TopDrive )
```

Now what i need is ,I want to insert data to column `TopDrive` only if the data is numeric.Else I want to insert "0" to that column.Is it possible in SQL?

Comment: What data type is the TopDrive column? Do you want to accept only integers or any form of number?

Comment: Instead you can validate in front end itself to accept only numbers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_LandRigs ([Company], [Rig], [RigType], [DrawWorks], [TopDrive])
VALUES (@Company, @Rig, @RigType, @DrawWorks, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@TopDrive) = 1 THEN @TopDrive ELSE 0 END)
```

Here we are putting both [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [`ISNUMERIC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) to good use.

Also, it usually makes it easier for other developers (or yourself at a later date) to be consistent with your usage of brackets and white space, even in SQL code.

As mentioned by others, `isnumeric` may give you some [false positives](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/).  If possible, it's often best to sanitize the input before it gets to your database, perhaps by not using untyped data in this case.  Only you know your inputs, but if you anticipate a problem, [there are some options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312054/efficient-isnumeric-replacements-on-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

There is an IsNumeric() function that you can call in SQL Server. Careful of scientific notation though...

Comment: Can you elaborate what i need to care with scientific notation?

Comment: If you have something like "1.23451e+04" or something like that, IsNumeric() will think that's a number...

Comment: `ISNUMERIC()` will also think `.`, `e`, `[tab]`, `$` and `€` are numeric. http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html

Answer (score 1):

Please see this:

```
IF Isnumeric(@TopDrive) = 1 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO TBL_LANDRIGS 
                  (COMPANY, 
                   RIG, 
                   [RIGTYPE], 
                   [DRAWWORKS], 
                   [TOPDRIVE]) 
      VALUES      (@Company, 
                   @Rig, 
                   @RigType, 
                   @DrawWorks, 
                   @TopDrive ) 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO TBL_LANDRIGS 
                  (COMPANY, 
                   RIG, 
                   [RIGTYPE], 
                   [DRAWWORKS], 
                   [TOPDRIVE]) 
      VALUES      (@Company, 
                   @Rig, 
                   @RigType, 
                   @DrawWorks, 
                   0 ) 
  END
```

Update if of any help

Comment: Is there a benefit to offset maintaining two insert statements?

Comment: @TimLehner: No absolutely not, If you ask me i would choose your answer :-D !

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting into sql you check whether it number or not check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669569/how-to-check-if-contents-of-a-string-are-numeric-values)

```
bool status;
NSScanner *scanner;
NSString *testString;
double result;

scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
status = [scanner scanDouble:&result];
status = status && scanner.scanLocation == string.length;
```

If `status == YES` then the string is fully numeric.

Or as @Dave points out from this SO answer:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
number = [formatter numberFromString:string];
status = number != nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking only for digits (no decimals) use `like '%[^0-9]%'` as below;

```
Insert into tbl_LandRigs (Company, Rig, [RigType], [DrawWorks], [TopDrive] ) 
Values (@Company, @Rig, @RigType, @DrawWorks,
        Case when @TopDrive like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else @TopDrive end )
```

Be careful with [ISNUMERIC()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) as it returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).