# Validation for numbers (0-9) in textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios, validation, uitextfield

I am trying to validate textfield for numbers only.

I am using the following method:

```
if(isnumber(noOfPassengers.text.intValue))
{
    NSLog(@"value entered correctly.");
    return ;
}
else
NSLog(@"Error: Only numerica values are accepted");
```

isnumber() function is not working as expected. I would like to validate for numbers only. Got stuck here. Any other inbuilt function to check for numbers or even characters?

Comment: Does this work? If not, what happens that is not as expected? Please be specific in where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Please could you give more information ie. what is wrong with your method that you used. Does the above method work as planned or is it just buggy code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone how to check that a string is numeric only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSScanner:

```
int iValue;

if (noOfPassengers.text.length > 0 && [[NSScanner scannerWithString:noOfPassengers.text] scanInt:&iValue]) {
    //do smomething with iValue (int value from noOfPassengers.text)
    NSLog(@"value entered correctly.");
    return ;
}
else
    NSLog(@"Error: Only numerica values are accepted");
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't posted any code for your function `isnumber`, so it's impossible to diagnose the problem there. However, writing the function from scratch, here is what I would do:

```
-(BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString*)inputString{
    NSCharacterSet *alphaNumbersSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *stringSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:inputString];
    return [alphaNumbersSet isSupersetOfSet:stringSet];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct thing to do here is to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a) to only accept numeric characters.

In the delegate method, return `YES` and strip any characters that aren't in the [decimal character set](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/decimalDigitCharacterSet).

Comment: The `isnumber()` function takes a C `char` and returns `1` if the char represents a decimal digit, otherwise it returns `0`. It can't do what you're asking for.

Comment: I like this better.  Better to fix it on the front end instead of letting the user enter something wrong and warning them.  Using this alongside a numeric keyboard presentation sounds good to me.

Answer (score -2):

for iOS, you should allow only numeric keyboard to appear instead. user will have no choice to input any other value except numbers..

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer to your question is just show Numeric keyboard and check the value then. You don't have to implement UITextFieldDelegate's @Ben.s suggested.

Comment: Users can still paste non-numeric text or use an external keyboard. If the code assumes a numeric input, this could break the app.