# how to change the font color of the special characters in a UITextview text

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsregularexpression

i am using this code to show some text in UITextview...in ViewDidLoad Method

```
self.fontSize = 23.0;
  for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
        [combined appendFormat:@"  %d %@", 
         idx + 1, 
         [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];

    };

    maintextview.text =combined;
    maintextview.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376f green:0.282f blue:0.173f alpha:1.0f];

    maintextview.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:self.fontSize];
```

`combined` has the text which includes numeric charter also,how can i identify the numeric character and put brown color and change font to Georgia-Bold only of numercharacters.is it possible by using NSSanner or NSregular expression or something like that?.
how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on a regular text view.  It does not allow formatting (although this is a greatly desired feature by many developers).  What you need to do is use Core Text and NSAttributedString with a custom view.  However, this is very difficult if you need to use selection, or have it be editable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only is this help for for me?

Comment: That will only work with the *entire* content of the text view.

Comment: }
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSNumber * n = [f numberFromString:combined]; 
    NSLog(@"N: %@", n);
i put this code but i get null value

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question...you mean you want to check if the entire string is numeric?

Comment: so there is no way to separate numeric from string in a text?

Comment: ,no i just want to get the numeric from my text ,and put a condition to textview if its numeric i want textview.textcolor = [uicolor red color]; if it i string (not numeric) i want the textolor to be green

Comment: So you mean red and green text in the same UITextView at the same time?  That is not possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11557/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-borrrden)

Answer (score 0):

alternate option is to make an HTML page and put web View instead of the TextView.

it saves your time.