# how to check whether the string value is from 0 to 9?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iphone application in which I want to check whether a string value is from 0 to 9. If it is like that, I want to do something else. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: 0 to 9 means its length or the character should be b/w 0 to 9 ?

Comment: I think that could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320295/iphone-how-to-check-that-a-string-is-numeric-only

Comment: What about localisation - what if you want to match the arabic numerals for example (which are ٠‎,١,‎٢,‎٣,‎٤,‎٥‎,٦,‎٧,‎٨,‎٩ (thanks, wikipedia!) .If you want to be language agnostic, you might want to change your accepted answer to the regular expression.

Comment: no i was accepted because that was exactly wat i want..and has a beautifull explanation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (string.length == 1 && [string characterAtIndex:0] >= '0' && [string characterAtIndex:0] <= '9') {
    // do something
}
```

This checks for the string being exactly 1 character long and that character being either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.

Comment: You missed '0'. Change the '1' to a '0' and you'll get every number you wanted. The reason the order works '0' to '9' is that these characters map to ASCII which was included in Unicode for the < 128 case.

Comment: excellent answer.....great job..everybody should have to demonstrate this when answering the stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *Number = @"0";
NSString *Regex = @"[0-9]"; 
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex]; 
BOOL matches = [test evaluateWithObject:Number];
NSLog(@"Status %d",matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *st=@"9"; // given number
    double val=[st doubleValue];
    int i=0;
       while(i==val)
       {
           if(i==val)
           { 
               NSLog(@"NUmber between 0 asnd 9");
               break;
           }
           else
           {
               i++;

           }
       }
```