# Get a range from a string

Tags: ios, swift, range, ios8, nsrange

I want to check if a string contains only numerals. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259654/1077789) answer written in Objective-C.

```
NSRange range = [myTextField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
if(range.location == NSNotFound) {
    // then it is numeric only
}
```

I tried converting it to Swift.

```
let range: NSRange = username.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())
```

The first error I came across is when I assigned the type `NSRange`.

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'Range?' to type 'NSRange'**

So I removed the `NSRange` and the error went away. Then in the if statement,

```
let range = username.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())
if range.location == NSNotFound {

}
```

I came across the other error.

**'Range?' does not have a member named 'location'**

Mind you the variable `username` is of type `String` not `NSString`. So I guess Swift uses its new `Range` type instead of `NSRange`.

The problem I have no idea how to use this new type to accomplish this. I didn't come across any documentation for it either.

Can anyone please help me out to convert this code to Swift?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an example how you can use it:

```
if let range = username.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()) {
    println("start index: \(range.startIndex), end index: \(range.endIndex)")
}
else {
    println("no data")
}
```

Comment: Is there way to compare it with `NSNotFound`? If I do this `let range = username.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()) == NSNotFound` I get this error, **'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<String.Index>'**

Comment: The else statement (no data) is equivalent with no found.

Comment: Yes i found a solution for this i am using this work for validate a string for that i am using this code
      var isValid = true 
      let name = self.TrimText(nameText) as NSString      
      let nameSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ- ")
      let set = nameSet.invertedSet
      let range = name.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(set)
      let isInvalidName = range.location != NSNotFound    
      if(isInvalidName){             
                isValid = false
            }

Comment: ^ I think he missed the point, you don't need `range.location` in Swift (nor `NSNotFound`. The `else` clause above alone, means it was not found.