# What is a good way to remove the formatting from a phone number to only get the digits?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

Is there a better or shorter way of striping out all the non-digit characters with Objective-C on the iPhone?

```
NSString * formattedNumber = @"(123) 555-1234";
NSCharacterSet * nonDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

NSString * digits;
NSArray * parts = [formattedNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigits];
if ( [parts count] > 1 ) {
    digits = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@""];
} else {
    digits = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
}
return digits;
```

Comment: Be aware that non-digits such as '+' are valid in phone numbers.

Comment: Phone numbers should only *start* with a +, according to [ITU-T E.123](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/en).

Comment: That is true, but I need to get the number into an Integer type.  I should have included that in the question detail.

Comment: Mack: Don't do that. Phone numbers can be larger than can fit into any of the integral types, especially when you include dialing codes, country codes, extensions, etc.; moreover, as dreamlax already told you, there are at least two (I would say three, the third being the comma) non-numeric characters that you *must not* strip. You will corrupt user input if you try to stuff the phone number into an integral type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all but numbers from NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a RegEx-replacement that replaces `[\D]` with nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Dupe of [Remove all but numbers from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring)

The accepted answer there involves using NSScanner, which seems heavy-handed for such a simple task.  I'd stick with what you have there (though someone in the other thread suggested a more compact version if it, thus:

```
NSString *digits = [[formattedNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
                       componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I was wondering whether the if statement was adding any value.

Answer (score 3):

Phone numbers can contain asterisks and number signs (`*` and `#`), and may start with a `+`. The [ITU-T E-123 Recommandation](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/en) recommends that the `+` symbol be used to indicate that the number is an international number and also to serve as a reminder that the country-specific international dialling sequence must be used in place of it.

Spaces, hyphens and parentheses cannot be dialled so they do not have any significance in a phone number. In order to strip out all useless symbols, you should remove all characters *not* in the decimal character set, except `*` and `#`, and also any `+` not found at the start of the phone number.

To my knowledge, there is no standardised or recommended way to represent manual extensions (some use `x`, some use `ext`, some use `E`). Although, I have not encountered a manual extension in a long time.

```
NSUInteger inLength, outLength, i;
NSString *formatted = @"(123) 555-5555";

inLength = [formatted length];
unichar result[inLength];

for (i = 0, outLength = 0; i < inLength; i++)
{
    unichar thisChar = [formatted characterAtIndex:i];

    if (iswdigit(thisChar) || thisChar == '*' || thisChar == '#')
        result[outLength++] = thisChar;   // diallable number or symbol
    else if (i == 0 && thisChar == '+')
        result[outLength++] = thisChar;   // international prefix
}

NSString *stripped = [NSString stringWithCharacters:result length:outLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
NSString *digits = [[formattedNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Noting 0xA3's comment above, you could optionally use a different NSCharacterSet that includes + and other non-digits that are valid in phone numbers.