# iphone sdk - Remove all numbers except for characters a-z from a string

Tags: iphone, string

In my app I want to remove numbers except characters a-z from string. How can I get only characters?

Comment: What version of the SDK/OS are you targetting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the short answer which doesnt need any lengthy coding

```
NSString *newString = [[tempstr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`
```

swift 3:

```
(tempstr.components(separatedBy:NSCharacterSet.letters.inverted)).joined(separator: "")
```

eg:

```
("abc123".components(separatedBy:NSCharacterSet.letters.inverted)).joined(separator: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringToFilter = @"filter-me";


    NSMutableString *targetString = [NSMutableString string];


    //set of characters which are required in the string......
    NSCharacterSet *okCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];


    for(int i = 0; i < [stringToFilter length]; i++)
    {
        unichar currentChar = [stringToFilter characterAtIndex:i];
        if([okCharacterSet characterIsMember:currentChar]) 
        {
            [targetString appendFormat:@"%C", currentChar];
        }
    }


    NSLog(targetString);    


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

this was an answer given to me and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:
from [remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring)

```
NSString *originalString = @"(123) 123123 abc";

NSLog(@"%@", originalString);
NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
                                   stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
                           characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", strippedString);
```

Comment: I'm no expert in xcode, but isn't there a simpler solution to perform that simple task?

Comment: I'm quite surprised this hasn't been seen before but this answer has been taken word for word from stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstringst not good to copy someone else answer like that.

Comment: sorry i didn't know about this link. Actually one of my friend gave this answer so i just copied here.. any how i will add ur link as reference to it.