# Convert an iPhone phone number format for a "dial-able" string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I am building an iphone app that reads a phone number from the address book and dial it (with some other things of course...:)). When I load the phone numbers from the AB they are in this following format: "1 (111) 111-1111" which is not "dial-able" when using this:

```
fullNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"tel:", phoneNum];
```

Why is that happening? What would be the best way to approach this? How could I convert the phone number into a string of digits (with no spaces or "-")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will strip out all non-numeric characters:

```
phoneNumDecimalsOnly = [[phoneNum componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: What about "+" signs for international numbers?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about removing specific characters from a string... Take a look at the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6) specifcally the method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`

You could do

```
fullNumer = [fullNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
fullNumer = [fullNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
fullNumer = [fullNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
fullNumer = [fullNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Obviously not the most efficient... but it should give you an idea of the method and how to strip out specific characters.

Another option that covers any character other than a number can be seen in the following SO post, this is likely a much better solution to your problem.

[Remove all but numbers from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring)

Answer (score 2):

The below code will allow only digits and `+` in the entered string.

```
phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
            [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+0123456789"]
             invertedSet]]
           componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```