# Getting digits from an NSString

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a string like `@"(256) 435-8115"` or `@"256-435-81-15"`. I need only the digits (this is a phone number). Is this possible? I haven't found an `NSString` method to do that.

Comment: take a look at NSRegularExpression: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is much simpler way:

```
-(NSString*)getNumbersFromString:(NSString*)String{
    NSArray* Array = [String componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                      [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSString* returnString = [Array componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return (returnString);

}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
NSString *stringWithPhoneNumber=@"(256) 435-8115";



NSArray *plainNumbersArray= 

[stringWithPhoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:

[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]invertedSet]];



NSString *plainNumbers = [plainNumbersArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];


NSLog(@"plain number is : %@",plainNumbers);
```

**OutPut:**
plain number is : 2564358115

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:` to remove characters you don't want such as `@"("` with `@""`