# Incompatible pointer type error when using NSMutableString and stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: ios

The purpose of the code shown below is to take a string from a textfield and remove commas and left parentheses, to prepare the contents for conversion to a float. For example, it takes the number 1,234,567 and changes it to 1234567.

The code snippet works, but returns an informational error "Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableString * from String *"

When I use NSString instead of NSMutableString, I get no errors, but the returned value is an empty string.

Using the NSMutableString methodology, what is the problem and how can I change this to eliminate the 'Incompatible pointer type" error.

```
NSMutableString *cleanedDataCellTest = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:datacellR2C2.text];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"-"];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Which line gives the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is a method of NSString, and the return value is also a NSString. So you can't assign the return value to a `NSMutableString` variable.

Instead you can use the method `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` from `NSMutableString`:

```
NSMutableString *cleanedDataCellTest = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"1,234,567"];
[cleanedDataCellTest replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, cleanedDataCellTest.length)];
[cleanedDataCellTest replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, cleanedDataCellTest.length)];
[cleanedDataCellTest replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"-" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, cleanedDataCellTest.length)];
[cleanedDataCellTest replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, cleanedDataCellTest.length)];
```

<strike>But, for the consideration of performance, I think use NSString and its method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is more efficient.</strike>

**UPDATE:**  Sorry, yesterday I didn't test the "performance". I did a test just now, by replacing some thing in a string (about 26KB), use NSMutableString with `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` is a little bit **more efficient**.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableString *cleanedDataCellTest = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:datacellR2C2.text];
[cleanedDataCellTest replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, cleanedDataCellTest.length)];
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:

Answer (score 1):

Switching to NSString worked for me...:

```
NSString *cleanedDataCellTest = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"1,234,098"];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"-"];
cleanedDataCellTest =  [cleanedDataCellTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"cleanedDataCellTest = %@", cleanedDataCellTest);
```

Shows:

```
cleanedDataCellTest = 1234098
```

Comment: There seem to be some [good solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring) for stripping everything but numbers.