# Removing Character issue from NSString in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, nscharacterset

I have a string with value "€100,000,000". I want to remove the '€'  and ',' at the same time. I am try to use `[NSCharacterSet symbolSet]` but this method only removes the '€' without removing the ','.

Comment: Can you show how you are doing that?

Comment: your code is working fine for me. 2012-09-05 19:20:53.950 test[17026:a0f] 100000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
-(NSString*)cleanString:(NSString*)str
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:str];
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"€,"];
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is [Remove all but numbers from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring) answer.

Alternative for fixed cleaning in string is:

```
string = [[string stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"€" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@""];
```

where string contains `"€100,000,000"`

Answer (score 0):

Commas are not symbols.  It's part of the `[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]`.  But if you use that set it will remove the decimal place holder (period).

You will just have to do two operation to get the result you want.

1. Use `[NSCharacterSet symbolSet]` which will take care of all symbols for currency.
2. Use the `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfStrin` to remove only the `","`