# How to process this NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I read data from an API  and I see this string: `text = "\n\Ufeff211419";`

How can can process it to have the result: `211419` ? I used `trim` function of `NSString`, but it did not work. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Go read the NSString docs. This would be really simple if you were familiar with the methods in that class.

Comment: Visit link below

[remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring

Comment: NSString shows error because of "\U" in ur string.

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
NSString *strippedString=@"";
    NSString *originalString = @"1This is my string.#/hfg34y387t59hguhfytfrg64r34nfr31234";
    for (int i=0; i<[originalString length]; i++) {
        if (isdigit([originalString characterAtIndex:i])) {
            strippedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c",strippedString,[originalString characterAtIndex:i]];


        }
    }
    NSLog(@"string is%@",strippedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`substringFromIndex` or `substringToIndex` would help!

Comment: Nekto added back tick characters around the method names so that they would be properly highlighted.