# filter all characters out of NSString except number and '+' operand

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a number in a string like so: `@"+316-55 840 659"`. I want this to transform to: `@"+31655840659"`.

Right now, I'm using this:

```
[[number componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                           [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                          componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Is there a way to modify `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` so that it allows the `+` as well?

Comment: Use a mutable character set to add additional characters.

Comment: See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9430111/1226963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do:

```
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789+"]
```

or:

```
[[[NSCharacterSet decimalCharacterSet] mutableCopy] addCharactersInString:@"+"]
```