# Remove unallowed characters from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

I want to allow only specific characters for a string.

Here's what I've tried.

```
NSString *mdn = @"010-222-1111";

NSCharacterSet *allowedCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+0123456789"];
NSString *trimmed = [mdn stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[allowedCharacterSet invertedSet]];
NSString *replaced = [mdn stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

The result of above code is as below. The result of replaced is what I want.

```
trimmed : 010-222-1111
replaced : 0102221111
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't `invertedSet` work?

One more weird thing here. If I removed the `invertedSet` part like

```
NSString *trimmed = [mdn stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:allowedCharacterSet];
```

The result is

```
trimmed : -222-
```

I have no idea what makes this result.

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129521/remove-all-but-numbers-from-nsstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` only removes occurrences in the beginning and the end of the string. That´s why when you take inverted set, no feasible characters are found in the beginning and end of the string and thus aren't removed either.

A solution would be:

```
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingCharacters:(NSString*)str inSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet {
    return [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I added this to `NSString` category.

Answer (score 0):

stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet is only removing chars at the end and the beginning of the string, which results in -222-. You have to do a little trick to remove all chars in the set

```
 NSString *newString = [[origString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
            [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
            componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```