# How can i remove special characters and spaces from string in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, special-characters, separator

In response from webservice i am getting this :

```
\r    "
\n
\r
\n[[
\n'c23aa136-417b-410f-961b-0db059012572'",
    "'name_test']",
    "[
\n'7abbc761-13a0-4a89-98e5-a1e1b38a85e0'",
    "'name']",
    "[
\n'05a09a4e-2564-4029-b38f-f91080bbc668'",
    "'TestTrackerName1']]"
```

now it has line breakers, paragraph breakers and `"[]'"` brackets, single quotes. I want to trim it in a way that i just have imei num and name thats it.

i have tried few things but couldnt get the desired result. I just would like to ask that is there any ready made methods which could do this for me (maybe iam missing) or i have to write the filtration code myself ?

Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: Improve the web service. How are you logging the string? Have you looked at the NSString API to see what it offers?

Comment: Its a pre-build system and kind a very old system, i dont have access to it. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129985/1228669 you can try this answer.