# How to remove numbers from a String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, numbers

I have a String like `"75003 Paris, France"` or `"Syracuse, NY 13205, USA"`.

I want to use the same code to remove all those numbers out of those Strings.

With expected output is
`"Paris, France"` or `"Syracuse, NY, USA"`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it with the `NSCharacterSet`

```
var str = "75003 Paris, France"

var stringWithoutDigit = (str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")

println(stringWithoutDigit)
```

Output :

```
Paris, France
```

Taken reference from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426819/3202193

Swift 4.x:

```
let str = "75003 Paris, France"

let stringWithoutDigit = (str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)).joined(separator: "")

print(stringWithoutDigit)
```

Comment: @KevinScience Welcome, but I have searched on stackoverflow and found one answer in objective-c, tried to do in swift and given to you :)

Comment: swift 4.1 

var str = "75003 Paris, France"
var stringWithoutDigit = (str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)).joined(separator: "")
print(stringWithoutDigit)