# Cocoa interface to MacOS X Keychain

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain

I've got a bit of Mac code that needs to store, access and update passwords in order to connect users with a web API. The right place to put this information should be the Mac Keychain, but there doesn't seem to be a cocoa interface (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785868/28035)) -- is this still correct?

I've looked at Apple's [Keychain documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), and the API seems incredibly clunky. I can store to it and retrieve records, but anything more complex seems to require a lot of thought as to what might go wrong (see [this list of error codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898-CH5g-CJBEABHG)).

Is there a better interface to the Mac keychain, aside from slogging through the C code? The closest I've come is [EMKeychain](https://github.com/irons/EMKeychain) but it seems like it needs a bit of work (e.g. no error handling code aside from spitting to the console).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should take a look at [**SSKeychain**](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain).  Works great, awesome code.

Comment: This could work, although I've been thinking the internet password seems a bit better of a match to my setup than the generic password system. I guess I could encode the url into the "service" that SSKeychain uses as an identifier. If there isn't anything better for my purposes, at least this is a starting point if I want to put together a system around the internet passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Too late answer but would be good for future help. Below is what I did to save the password in Keychain of Mac

```
#pragma -mark Password save in Keychain

-(NSURLProtectionSpace *)createProtectionSpaceForBasicAuthentication{

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                             initWithHost:@"http://yourURLHere"
                                             port:1804  //add Your port here
                                             protocol:@"http" //can be pass as nil 
                                             realm:nil
                                             authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];
    return protectionSpace;
}

-(void )createCredentialForUsername:(NSString *)username Password:(NSString *)password{

    NSURLCredential *credentialObject;
    credentialObject = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:credentialObject forProtectionSpace:[self createProtectionSpaceForBasicAuthentication]];
}
```

For saving password

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self createCredentialForUsername:@"User_Name" Password:@"Your_Pass"];
}
```

for fetching the password

```
NSURLCredential *credential;
NSDictionary *credentials;
credentials = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] credentialsForProtectionSpace:[self createProtectionSpaceForBasicAuthentication]];
credential = [credentials.objectEnumerator nextObject];
    NSLog(@"Username: %@ and password %@", credential.user, credential.password);
```

When we run the app to fetch password, we will get user action prompt for keychain access.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, as always, but I can recommend [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore).