# Tutorial on sskeychain and basic auth for iPad apps?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, basic-authentication, sskeychain

Where can I find a good detailed tutorial using [sskeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) to store and retrieve usernames and passwords and to do basic authentication in a UIWebView?  Secondarily, am I on the right track as far as the methods needed to store and use authentication for a web based application? (See explanation below.)

I found a couple tutorials using different methods:

- [Interacting with keychain directly](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)
- [Handmade keychain wrapper](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) (sic)
- [SFHFKeychainUtils](http://gorgando.com/blog/technology/iphone_development/simple-iphone-tutorial-password-management-using-the-keychain-by-using-sfhfkeychainutils)

According to recommendations from other SO questions below, sskeychain is recommended for an easier use of the keychain to store authentication parameters.

- [Cocoa interface to MacOS X Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864234/cocoa-interface-to-macos-x-keychain)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381072/save-username-and-password-for-url-like-gmail-com-iphone

My plan is to store a username and password locally on the device in the keychain as recommended and connect over a UIWebView using basic auth to my PHP code.  Is there a good step by step tutorial for xcode/Obj-C newbies on the topic of user authentication that would be recommended by experienced iOS developers?

The Apple documentation seems less than helpful. It's either pages with simple sales jargon or just head imploding descriptions of methods and parameters without many helpful examples.

**Update:**

I ended up just using NSUserDefaults to store the username and password locally and the AFNetworking library to do the authentication.  If these are unwise I'd welcome an answer that supplies guidance on a better method.

Comment: As you may know already, using ```NSUserDefaults``` to store username and password is unwise [indeed](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad). Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18485797/1264909) below to understand why and learn how to use ```SSKeychain```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do basic auth, you might be better off using a networking service like AFNetworking.  They all you to create a webclient, pass in a username/password combination and they take care of the rest.

This link show you the exact method call you need to invoke:
http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:

There is also a large community and a bunch of examples of developers using AFNetworking in all types of iOS project.

Comment: Can you cite some of the "bunch of examples"?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjig7ZnH73Y

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty because I'm going with this method.  I'll leave the answer unchecked because no one has shown how the keychain method can be used.  I'm also trying to track down now how to get the AFHTTPRequestOperation to supply my UIWebview with the response from the server in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676126/pass-response-from-afhttprequestoperation-to-uiwebview

Answer (score 13):

Using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) to do the authentication and calls to the server is great! But I would highly discourage you from storing credentials (username and password) in `NSUserDefaults`, since the contents are stored in a plist as plain text and can be read just by plugging your device to a mac. I recommend you to check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795506/storing-authentication-tokens-on-ios-nsuserdefaults-vs-keychain) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712260/storing-authentication-token-on-ios) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app) and [great post of a well-known case](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad) for further details on the topic.

You were right going for `Keychain` and using [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain/) is easy and fast. You can find this good example on [how to use SSKeychain to locally store the credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663948/how-to-choose-account-and-service-values-for-sskeychain).

```
// Store credentials in Keychain
[SSKeychain setPassword:@"thePassword"
             forService:@"com.yourCompany.yourApp"
                account:@"theUserName"];

// Retrieve credentials from Keychain
NSString *password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"com.yourCompany.yourApp"
                                            account:@"theUserName"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to you to use

[Lockbox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox/)

It's lightweight, works with ARC and easy to use.