# Fecebook access token Storage For ouath implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using facebook login in my iphone app and am accessed  some basic details from Facebook  API such as name, dob, email , username for user creation. I want to store access token for each user . Need your help in this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12715346/638127

Comment: Don't click the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the duration of the access token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/