# how can i store my access token to defaults or into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

i want to hit an API at login then i'll get a access token then whenever i"ll run my app it moves directly to homepage but m unable to get the access token there,how can i achieve this.my homepage Conditions are not getting access token simply.

Comment: For using NSUserDefaults. refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3074489/5215474

Comment: Consider using the keychain instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16795674/433373

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use user defaults objective c save your token**

```
NSString *token = @“yourToken”;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: token forKey:@“Token”];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Get your token**

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"Token"];
```

**Swift3.0 code save data**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(“yourToken”, forKey: “Token”)

// Get the Token from UserDefaults
if let token = defaults.value(forKey: “Token”) as? String {
    print("defaults Token: \(token)")
}
```

Comment: You do not need to call `synchronize`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a success response from login API.
write this line after your response and before you push to homepage.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Token" forKey:@"accessToken"];
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to achieve using `NSUserDefaults`

*Step 1:* When login API called and got the response, then save the **accessToken** in user defaults, like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"yourAccessToken" forKey:@"AccessTokenKey"];
```

*Step 2:* Retrieve the saved **accessToken** you have saved in user defaults whenever you required throughout the project, like:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AccessTokenKey"];
```

Happy coding...

Comment: You do not need to call `synchronize`.

Comment: ok, I have updated my code, I have added this becoz I had coded this in xcode 5. So I put the code here. Thanks