# How convert string in phone number format? objective c

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I want to convert string into phone number format. For example I have string in which I have value, "456897012". Now I want to convert it in phone number format like as (456)897-012.
So what is process for that? How can I do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: @Brian Roach Man brilliant link, I never seen that before..one to bookmark..

Comment: Not a direct answer, but will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665111/nsnumberformatter-to-format-us-telephone-numbers

Comment: I have the exact same problem. While we can code this ourself, there should be a standard code for this common problem. Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: This question is NOT ambiguous. It's not vague, incomplete or overly broad. Yes OP is lazy. But ambiguous he is not. C'mon guys.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work out I guess;

```
NSString *unformatted = @"5129876985";
NSArray *stringComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)], 
                             [unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 3)], 
                             [unformatted substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, [unformatted length]-6)], nil];

NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)%@-%@", [stringComponents objectAtIndex:0], [stringComponents objectAtIndex:1], [stringComponents objectAtIndex:2]];
NSLog(@"Formatted Phone Number: %@", formattedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok

Suppose you have the oldPhone

```
[oldPhone insertString: @"(" atIndex: 0];

[oldPhone insertString: @")" atIndex: 4];

[oldPhone insertString: @"-" atIndex: 9];
```

Have not test it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Wow...i forget the "objective", its ok, convert it to objective c:P
the logic is the same:P