# String to Phone Number format on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, phone-number

In my app, I have a string like:

> "3022513240"

I want to convert this like:

> (302)-251-3240

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone number formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting)

Comment: @ColinE: that is for 'real-time' formatting during text input. OP is asking about how to format a 'ready made' string. Even though the answers from the linked question could definetly help the OP.

Comment: See [RMPhoneFormat](https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat).

Comment: check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting

Comment: I solve this by following Link:

[Phone format][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425574/how-convert-string-in-phone-number-format-objective-c

Comment: That isn't a valid phone number format in my country...

Comment: I solve this as following:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425574/how-convert-string-in-phone-number-format-objective-c

Comment: @user1673099 I hope you understand that your chosen solution only works in two countries and not the rest of the world. Your requirements are unclear from your question but your app will be used all over the world. Phone number formats are different in every country. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a Swift extension that formats strings into phone numbers for 10 digit numbers.

```
extension String {    
    public func toPhoneNumber() -> String {
        return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", withString: "($1) $2-$3", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
    }
}
```

For example:

```
let number = "1234567890"
let phone = number.toPhoneNumber()
print(phone)
// (123) 456-7890
```

**Updated to Swift 3.0**:

```
extension String {
    public func toPhoneNumber() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", with: "($1) $2-$3", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I would do this way:

Example:

```
 NSMutableString *stringts = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.ts.text];
 [stringts insertString:@"(" atIndex:0];
 [stringts insertString:@")" atIndex:4];
 [stringts insertString:@"-" atIndex:5];
 [stringts insertString:@"-" atIndex:9];
 self.ts.text = stringts;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. Helped me much. Especially, when the US/Canada format should work the same in whatever locale. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

Handles 10 and 11 digit phone numbers that may or may not already have formatting or non-digit characters in the string.

Will handle:

- 1234567890, 12345678901, 123 456 7890, 123-456-7890, (123) 456-7890, 1-234-567-8901

Result:

- (999)-999-9999
- 1(999)-999-9999

Code:

```
extension String {

    /// Handles 10 or 11 digit phone numbers
    ///
    /// - Returns: formatted phone number or original value
    public func toPhoneNumber() -> String {
        let digits = self.digitsOnly
        if digits.count == 10 {
            return digits.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", with: "($1)-$2-$3", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        }
        else if digits.count == 11 {
            return digits.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{1})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", with: "$1($2)-$3-$4", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        }
        else {
            return self
        }
    }

}

extension StringProtocol {

    /// Returns the string with only [0-9], all other characters are filtered out
    var digitsOnly: String {
        return String(filter(("0"..."9").contains))
    }

}
```

Example:

```
let num = "1234567890"
let formatted = num.toPhoneNumber()
// Formatted is "(123)-456-7890"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension String {
public func toPhoneNumber() -> String {
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", with: "$1-$2-$3", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
}}
```

**Result**
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://github.com/me2day/libPhoneNumber-iOS) way

```
NSError *aError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *myNumber1 = [phoneUtil parse:@"6766077303" defaultRegion:@"AT" error:&aError];
if (aError == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"isValidPhoneNumber ? [%@]", [phoneUtil isValidNumber:myNumber1] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"E164          : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatE164]);
    NSLog(@"INTERNATIONAL : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatINTERNATIONAL]);
    NSLog(@"NATIONAL      : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatNATIONAL]);
    NSLog(@"RFC3966       : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber1 numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatRFC3966]);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", [aError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: i use this but first time enter number and second time same call so app crash.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex like `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})` and replace input matching the pattern  with `($1)-$2-$3`

Comment: This only supports a limited set of phone numbers.

Comment: @rmaddy OP stated that `3022513240` like numbers have to be converted to `(302)-251-3240` like format. For that the given regex suffices.why downvote as the question remains so?

Comment: I was simply making an observation. The OP may not understand that their app may be used by people all over the world and that phone numbers are formatted differently in every country. But yes, if the user really only needs to format phone numbers in the USA and Canada, your regular expression will work.

Comment: @rmaddy i don't think that's a useful observation as long as the OP wants to change the number to a particular format as stated only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RMPhoneFormat](https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat) library for formatting phone numbers.
The formatting should replicate what you would see in the Contacts app for the same phone number.

Comment: Edwin, this would be accepted in the AppStore? I see it uses some private framework.

Comment: If it does, then I was lucky last time I submitted my app. If you are sure about this, then could you create an issue for this on github? On what file/line do you see this?

Comment: The readme file says that. I ended up using the library that ishtar mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Ah, it uses a copy of a file from a private framework. It is not using the private framework itself. You can use it because it's a copy. The note says: This class depends on a copy of an Apple provided private framework file named Default.phoneformat being copied into the app's resource bundle and named PhoneFormats.dat.

Comment: @NatanR. I also using this but I check that It does not matching with the formate which is used by contact app and for india(+91) it shows different formate and also for USA. Please help me I am just want to implement same functionality for contact app itself. thanks . I also post a question please reply here or on my question stackoverflow.com/questions/32390073/ios-native-phone-formater

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple and easy

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if (string.length) {
       if (textField.text.length<=13) {
           if (textField.text.length==3) {
               NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)- ",textField.text];
               textField.text=tempStr;
           } else if (textField.text.length==8) {
               NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",textField.text];
               textField.text=tempStr;
           }
       } else {
           return NO;
       }
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [RMPhoneFormat](https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat), its great I used it.

Comment: I also using this but I check that It does not matching with the formate which is used by contact app and for india(+91) it shows different formate and also for USA. Please help me I am just want to implement same functionality for contact app itself. thanks . I also post a question please reply here or on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390073/ios-native-phone-formater

Comment: https://github.com/tunabelly/RMPhoneFormat as added support for string with 12+ digits. did you try this fork ? I know an issue as been open for india format. USA format should be good, I used it for Canada/USA and it was good last I used it. but its been a while since then. Edit: have you tried https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS this lib look active last update was last month.

Comment: user100 page not found

Answer (score 0):

I used the [`SHSPhoneNumberFormatter`](https://github.com/Serheo/SHSPhoneComponent) to do this so I don't have to change the type or subclass my `UITextField`

To set it up:

```
let phoneNumberFormatter = SHSPhoneNumberFormatter()
phoneNumberFormatter.setDefaultOutputPattern("(###) ###-####")
```

Listen for the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` and run the following:

```
let phoneDict = phoneNumberFormatter.valuesForString(phoneTextField.text) 
phoneTextField.text = phoneDict["text"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code to convert string to phone number format**

**Swift 3**

```
func PhoneNumberFormate( str : NSMutableString)->String{
        str.insert("(", at: 0)
        str.insert(")", at: 4)
        str.insert("-", at: 8)
        return str as String
    }
```

**to use**

```
let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: "3022513240")
let strModify = self.PhoneNumberFormate(str: nsMutableString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* formatPhoneNumber(NSString* phoneNumber, NSString *mask) {
    // Remove any non-numeric characters from the phone number string
    NSString* strippedNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                                [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                               componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    // Check if the phone number is the correct length
    if (strippedNumber.length != [mask componentsSeparatedByString:@"X"].count) {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    // Initialize a string for the formatted phone number
    NSString* formattedNumber = mask;
    int i = 0;
    // Iterate through the mask, replacing "X" with corresponding digits
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < formattedNumber.length; j++) {
        if ([formattedNumber characterAtIndex:j] == 'X') {
            formattedNumber = [formattedNumber stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1) withString:[strippedNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return formattedNumber;
}
```